# Nginx url rewrite file not found

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, mod-rewrite

I have converted my `.htaccess` to work with Nginx but i have many 404 errors or wrong display for folder and subfolder rewriting.

This Nginx config works for folder and subfolder but for `/view/` its going to `/home/website/www/index.php`

the `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^view/execute(.+)$ /home/website/view/exec.php?r=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^view/status$ /home/website/view/status.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /home/website/www/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /home/website/www/index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And Nginx config:

```
listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /home/website/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name example.com;

error_page 404 /home/website/error/index.php?er=404;

location / {
    set $1 "/index.php";
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
    root   /home/website/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php @rewrites =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

# rewrites
location @rewrites {
   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /home/website/www/index.php?a=$1;
   rewrite ^view/execute(.*)$ /home/website/view/execute.php?a=$1;
   #rewrite ^view/(.*)$ /home/website/view/index.php?a=$1 last;
}
```

Thanks.

Edit

I have this error:  `[error] 2329#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/website/www/home/website/www/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, request: "GET /view/execute/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:"`

With alias

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?a=$uri;
}
location /view/execute {
    index test.txt;
    alias /home/website/view;
}
```

Its work with `test.txt` but if i change with `test.php` i have this error `'No input file specified.'`

My folder is like that:

```
- /home/
  - /website/
    - /view/
      - execute.php
      - test.php
      - test.txt
    - /www/
      - index.php 
    - /function/
```

url like that example.com/registre/confirm work but this url example.com/view/execute not work :/
I tested to give permision +x with recursive for folder /view/ but not work too

Sorry for all this question im noob lol

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx configuration isn't good at all. Try something like this:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /home/website/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name example.com;

error_page 404 /home/website/error/index.php?er=404;

location / {
    rewrite ^view/execute(.*)$ /home/website/view/execute.php?a=$1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /home/website/www/index.php?a=$uri;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

So, the main problems in your configuration were:

1. rewrite lines were in wrong order in @rewrites block, therefore the latter rewrite was never reached, because the first rewrite rule was always matched.
2. PHP location block had a not-needed try_files rule, which might cause problems with PHP files.

If the configuration above doesn't work, you can try replacing the `try_files` line with these lines:

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /home/website/www/index.php?a=$1;
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Comment: Thanks for anwser but unfortunately not work :/ I tested your 2 solution, alias, root folder (like `/home/website/www/` and `/home/website`) i edit my first post with error log